# Developing public site using vs 2010, authentication should be?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I'm developing a public web site in vs2010,
can I keep the authentication as windows authentication and just enable anon access
or should I leave it with the default forms authentication.

The site will NOT require any type of logging in mechanism...so really I dont see a point in forms authentication, but most users will not have windows authentication either.

So I am confused, in my asp.net web.config file what authentication do I use for a public website?

I also asked this question which is kind of related: [developing site in vs2010 but changed to local IIS and prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961964/developing-site-in-vs2010-but-changed-to-local-iis-and-prompts/6962038#6962038)

But I am not having any luck with this :(.  The site when using local IIS keeps prompting for a user name and password (See the stackoverflow question I posted above), ive checked the app pools, the security, and the permissions and it still prompts me for a user name and password.  It prompts me about 10 times and if I keep cancelling out of it the page comes up but the images are not displayed nor is the CSS rendered.  So it looks like it prompts for each image on the site, but all folders inherit from the parent and I've added Network, Network service, ASPNET user, the default app pool user...I dont know what else to do.

So two issues:

1) What do I specify in my web config for a public site
2) How do I get rid of this prompting!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify specify any authentication. Just deploy it as is, with the Web.Config out of the box.

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

Go [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-config-file-demystified/) for more reading.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is prompting you with a login dialog, try using an authorization element in your web.config file with any authentication you like.  Use "*" to allow access to all users by default.  Refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) for more detail.

```
<authorization>
   <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config file has two sections that control requests for login. These are

```
<authentication> ... </authentication>
```

and

```
<authorisation> --- </authorization>
```

Authorization controls who can access what, and Authentication determines how the credentials of a particular user are established to see if they have the correct authorization to access your site.

An example of their usage might be

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="40320" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

which allows access to all users to the root of my applications and their credentials are determined using forms authentication.

Other parts of your site are allowed to have alternate authorization requirements through the use of a location tag in your web.config

However, neither section is required if no part of your site requires this functionality. However, you should be aware that there other places that this might be determined. There is a file called machine.config that determines the settings for the machine. Your web.config has priority over the machine.config, but if the authorization and authentication settings are made in the machine.config and not in you web.config then the machine.config wins.

Hope that helps. If you can post your web.config that might help us to point you in the right direction.